# Binding to pageinit event generates a white page with spinner

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, spinner

I'm binding to the jQuery Mobile `pageinit` event to do some additional stuff after a page has been created/enhanced and loaded into the DOM (per the docs) like so:

```
$('#home').live('pageinit', function()
{
    ...
};
```

But, all I'm getting is a white spinner and the page never displays on an iOS device running OS6. It works fine in the simulator. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of references to pageinit not working if placed in the wrong part of the page, though generally that wouldn't cause the page to stop loading.

A script error in the event handler (the ... part) could cause the symptoms described, but would likely work the same in the simulator.

Are you sure all the files are referenced correctly? Unlike OSX, iOS is case sensitive, so a reference to jQuery.js instead of jquery.js will cause problems that you can't see anywhere else. You should be able to connect the desktop safari web inspector to the app to find any load errors.